# Swap Composite Command Components

Tags: expression-manipulation, expression-construction, code

Let's take a composite Mathematica command:

```
A[B[]]
```

where `A` and `B` - two arbitrary Mathematica commands and `[]` - inner object of arbitrary structure

What code to use to swap them, i.e.:

`A[B[]]`$\xrightarrow{\text{?}}$`B[A[]]`

*for example:*

`D[Sin[]]`$\xrightarrow{\text{?}}$`Sin[D[]]`

Let's also consider a more complicated case:

for expression `D[Transpose[x] + Sin[x y], x]`

we must get `Transpose[D[x, x]] + Sin[D[x y, x]]`

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you please elaborate more on what you are _actually_ trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D is the derivative operator in MMA. Therefore, I am using DD.

You may achieve your goal  using "ReplaceAll" with the following pattern:

```
pat= x1_[x2_[x3_]] -> x2[x1[x3]]
```

With this, e.g.:

```
DD[Sin[a]] /. pat
(* Sin[DD[a]] *)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, to work with the `D` command, I need to use `Unprotect` and `Protect`? It all boils down to working with the rules one way or another... It would be interesting to try some alternatives. Is it possible to avoid the removal of protection from the `D` command?

Comment: @dtn, are you really saying that you want to override `D`, or are you saying that `D` just happens to be one of the heads you want to swap with? If the latter, then it gets more complicated, because `D` expects more than one argument.

Comment: @lericr "`D` expects more than one argument." Actually `D[a]` returns `a`, this is a surprisng hidden syntax :) . You may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/1871

Comment: @lericr I just realized that it's much more complicated than that. So we are talking about a more complex version. Let's say ... there is such an expression `D[Transpose[x] + Sin[x y], x]`, and the desired result should look like `Transpose[D[x, x]] + Sin[D[x y, x]]`

Comment: @xzczd, yeah, I assumed that form wasn't meaningful, or was used "accidentally" in the example.

Comment: @dtn, sigh. Now that things are getting more complicated, I think you're probably going to want to roll your own function. It'll probably need to be explicitly told which heads to swap (because Mathematica will normalize the order of terms, and it just gets messy to try to handle all cases with patterns), it'll probalby need to hold its arguments, and you'll probably have to use Unevaluated/Hold*/Inactive or some combination of similar constructs.

Comment: @lericr https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275494/67019 please, see this answer. As far as I understand, the `MapAt` command "injects" the target function into the body of other functions included in the expression. This is a simpler version of the solution to the particular case that I gave in my comment. Here is my code using this command: `expr[x_, y_] = Transpose[x] + Sin[x y];` `MapAt[D[#, x] &, expr[x, y], {All, 1}]` And the answer is just: `Transpose[D[x, x]] + Sin[D[x y, x]]`